# C#: отправка Email через SmtpClient в кодировке cp1251

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Добрый день.

Я использую **SmtpClient** для отправки почты. Мне требуется отправить имейл в кодировке **cp1251**. Я пробовал прописывать заголовок вручную :

```
            m.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            m.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            m.Headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain; charset=windows-1251";
```

но без толку.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?**

Спасибо

Comment: А вы уверены, что `Encoding.Default` — именно cp1251?

Comment: Даже указать там кодировку cp1251, результат не изменится

Answer (score 1):

Не в каждой системе есть предустановленная кодировка `Windows-1251` (Кириллица), и даже если она есть - далеко не факт что она установлена по умолчанию. Поэтому советую перевести клиент\сервер на `UTF-8`. Т.е. Вы выставили кодировку `Encoding.Default` (по умолчанию берется из кодовой страницы ANSI операционной системы), можно провести эксперимент - вывести название текущей кодировки, например так:

```
Encoding.Default.EncodingName
```

Answer (score 0):

а может использовать Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

Comment: Encoding cp1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

                m.SubjectEncoding = cp1251; // Encoding.Default;
                m.BodyEncoding = cp1251; // Encoding.Default;
                m.Headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain; charset=windows-1251"; --- не работает

Comment: не работает, пробовал. но спасибо за ответ